# Validate Google OAuth 2 access token in Ruby with googleauth gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I have a front end React app that consumes data from a Rails 7 API. The app uses Sign in with Google. On each request to the API, it includes the access token received from Google in the `Authorization` header and that's the point where I'm stuck. I want to validate the token in a `before_action` in my Rails controllers. All signs indicate that the `googleauth` gem is the way to do this, but I can't figure out how to do it and docs are minimal. So far I have this code:

```rb
def validate_access_token
  access_token = request.headers['Authorization']&.gsub(/bearer /i, '')
  key_source = Google::Auth::IDTokens::HttpKeySource.new('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs')
  verifier = Google::Auth::IDTokens::Verifier.new(key_source:)
  verifier.verify(access_token)
rescue Google::Auth::IDTokens::VerificationError => e
  # Handle error and return unauthorized response
end
```

I have tested this on several tokens I know are valid and it has raised signature errors, saying the token can't be verified as issued by Google. It's possible I'm using the wrong key source but I don't know what other one to use because, again, docs for Ruby are nonexistent.

I'm using version 1.3.0 of the googleauth gem. I've also tried using Faraday to contact Google's tokeninfo endpoint and gotten similar results. I don't know why it's saying my tokens are invalid when I just got them directly from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that somehow I was using the wrong key to verify the access token, so further investigation led me to this blog post: https://mpierrax.medium.com/firebase-authentification-with-ruby-on-rails-backend-a9f7afc4d715

The solution here was to make sure I was using the correct key value and, once I was doing that, use Faraday (any HTTP client would work) to contact the validation API endpoint directly.

Answer (score 0):

did you provide any value for `key_source` when initializing `Google::Auth::IDTokens::Verifier`?

try

```
verifier = Google::Auth::IDTokens::Verifier.new(key_source: Google::Auth::IDTokens::JwkVerifier::DEFAULT_CERT_URI)
verifier.verify(token)
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too. I finally ended up using Faraday to verify with the API directly. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

`googleauth` gem v1.5.2

```rb
key_source = Google::Auth::IDTokens::JwkHttpKeySource.new(Google::Auth::IDTokens::OAUTH2_V3_CERTS_URL)
verifier = Google::Auth::IDTokens::Verifier.new(key_source: key_source)
verifier.verify(token)
```